# How can I make it such that a pthread wastes cpu time for a total of 1 second in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

So I have an assignment that compares algorithms for allocating resources. I've implemented the algorithms and they work fine. My problem is simulating work being done on those resources.

Originally, I figured just sleep for a second and that will do fine. However, that doesn't actually waste CPU time. All of the resources can go to sleep at the same time and 3 seconds of simulated work would be done in 1 second...which is impossible.

How can I make it such that the thread remains active and only after spending a total of 1 second in the CPU will it continue and do other things?

Comment: You need a loop, of course. You also need the current time. And you need to compare the time before the loop with the current time. The rest should be easy to figure out.

Comment: I considered that, but it wouldn't work because I have an unknown amount of threads going. Sure it would be 1 second, but not 1 second in the CPU.

Comment: You can get the real time, not just CPU time.

Comment: OH, wait, you do want CPU time, sorry.

Comment: Yeah. The idea is to time how efficient the allocation algorithms are, so I'm trying to simulate some pretend work in the CPU when resources get allocated. This way I can compare how much actual work is done when comparing the algorithms.

Comment: You will very seldom be able to get an exact amount of CPU time, not even with direct access to the CPU and its own timers. The closest you can get (with standard functions) is probably the [`clock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) function.

Comment: I never did anything like that, but maybe `pthread_getcpuclockid` can help you ( surely there is no portable solution to this, but you tagged it `pthread`, so this might work in that context )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `pthread_getcpuclockid(3)` is mandated by POSIX. It's (Linux) manual page contains a short example that gives the CPU time used up by a thread. Run in a loop until you've wasted enough time, looping around doing some thumb twiddling in between checks.